# Hashing a tuple in C++17

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, hashcode, c++17

C++ doesn't supply a `std::hash<std::tuple<...>>`, so I decided to implement one. However, I was viewing this as more of a hash library than extensions to `std`, so I placed it all under the namespace `utils`.

This was my first time seriously using template meta-progamming. I tried to make my code work no matter the cv-ness of the variable, or whether it was an rvalue or an lvalue. I'm not sure on the efficiency of execution, but I believe the compiler can optimize it down to simple arithmetic on hash values.

**hash.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdint>

namespace utils {

template<class T>
struct hash
{
    template<class Type>
    std::size_t operator()(Type && v) const {
        return std::hash<T>()(std::forward<Type>(v));
    }
};


namespace internal {
    // A simple algorithm for combining two hash values,
    // algorithm from boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine
    constexpr inline std::size_t hash_combine(std::size_t hash1, std::size_t hash2) {
        return hash1 ^ (hash2 * 0x9e3779b9 + (hash1 << 6) + (hash1 >> 2));
    }

    // Necessary to hold a value so that we can use the fold operator
    struct hash_combine_t
    {
        const std::size_t value;
    };

    // % because it's a non-commutative operator that has been used for things other than
    // it's "intended" purpose before (e.g. string formatting)
    constexpr hash_combine_t operator%(const hash_combine_t &lhs, const hash_combine_t &rhs) {
        return { hash_combine(lhs.value, rhs.value) };
    }

    template<class... Ts>
    constexpr std::size_t hash_combine_impl(Ts&&... args) {
        return (hash_combine_t{ static_cast<std::size_t>(args) } % ...).value;
    }

    template<class... Ts>
    constexpr std::size_t hash_all_impl(Ts&&... args) {
        return hash_combine_impl(utils::hash<std::decay_t<Ts>>()(std::forward<Ts>(args))...);
    }
}

template<class... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t hash_combine(Ts&&... args) {
    return internal::hash_combine_impl(args...);
}

template<class... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t hash_all(Ts&&... args) {
    return internal::hash_all_impl(static_cast<std::decay_t<Ts>>(args)...);
}

template<class... Ts>
struct hash<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
private:
    // We have this impl_t struct in order to support hashing of the empty tuple:
    //     std::tuple<>
    // The struct gives us partial template specification.
    template<std::size_t I, class Tuple>
    struct impl_t {
        std::size_t operator()(Tuple && tuple) const {
            // If this was called with an lvalue, we need to add an lvalue reference to our
            // types in order to get the correct utils::hash_all function.
            // utils::hash_all<Ts...> does not work; only things similar to
            // utils::hash_all<Ts&...> would work, but then it would not work for
            // rvalues as well.
            //
            // So we determine whether this was called with an lvalue by using std::is_reference<Tuple>.
            return std::apply(
                utils::hash_all<
                    std::conditional_t<
                        std::is_reference<Tuple>::value,
                        std::add_lvalue_reference_t<Ts>,
                        std::add_rvalue_reference_t<Ts>
                    >...
                >,
                std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)
            );
        }
    };
    template<class Tuple>
    struct impl_t<0, Tuple> {
        std::size_t operator()(Tuple && tuple) const {
            // 0 is a good value for the empty tuple; there is only one empty tuple
            return 0;
        }
    };
public:
    template<class Tuple>
    std::size_t operator()(Tuple && tuple) const {
        return impl_t<sizeof...(Ts), Tuple>()(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    }
};

}
```

Comment: check out https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/HowardHinnant/papers/blob/master/hashing.html#hash_append

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we can definitely simplify that:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
```

### Forward Declaration.

```
template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... ids>
std::size_t tupleHash(Tuple const& tuple, std::index_sequence<ids...> const&);
```

### Hash All Types

```
template<typename T>
std::size_t hashValue(T const& value)
{
    // SFINAE kicks in here for tuples.
    // There is no std::hash that works for tuples.
    // So this candidate will be ignored if you use a tuple.
    std::hash<T>    hasher;
    return hasher(value);
}
```

#### Have a version for Tuples.

```
template<typename... Args>
std::size_t hashValue(std::tuple<Args...> const& value)
{
    return tupleHash(value, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
}
// Special case the empty tuple (as Args... can not be the empty list).
std::size_t hashValue(std::tuple<> const& value)
{
    // Not an expert in hashing.
    // Do some appropriate thing to get a value;
    return 1;
}
```

#### Do all the work in a helper function.

```
template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... ids>
std::size_t tupleHash(Tuple const& tuple, std::index_sequence<ids...> const&)
{
    // Not an expert in hashing.
    // Not sure 0 is a good seed (or this algorithm is good) solely here for demo purpose.
    std::size_t  result = 0;
    for(auto const& hash: {hashValue(std::get<ids>(tuple))...})
    {
        result ^= hash + 0x9e3779b9 + (result<<6) + (result>>2);
    }
    return result;
};
```

#### Tests

```
int main()
{
    auto tp = std::make_tuple(1,2,"Loki");
    std::cout << hashValue(tp) << "\n";

    auto ttp = std::make_tuple(4,tp,8,tp);
    std::cout << hashValue(ttp) << "\n";

    auto et = std::make_tuple();
    std::cout << hashValue(et) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @justin: It was just supposed to show where to combine the values. I did not want to look up an actual hash combining function as there are a couple out there and it would be arbitrary which one I chose (as I have no context for the use case).

Comment: This fails for nested tuples. You could define `Hash` as a specialization of `std::hash` and then it would work for that, but I wanted to not specialize `std::hash`.

Comment: This also fails for the empty tuple, but a specialization for `hash` would fix that

Comment: @Justin: Do you want me sit down tonight and actually work on real version rather than giving you hints on how to improve your code?

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across as demanding. I didn't understand that you were suggesting improvements rather than saying "this is a much better way to do it, just use this code instead"

Comment: Under the section **Hash All Types**, you say that SFINAE kicks in, but the error will not be in the type-substitution phase of `hashValue` . Is this an oversight, or am I missing something?

Comment: sp2danny is right. And I don't even think what you wrote is using SFINAE at all, it's just overload resolution.